# Duty cycle of CW-tone

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-theory

How is the duty cycle for a CW<sup>1</sup>-tone defined? A CW-tone has a duty cycle of 1, but how can you define the duty cycle for a sine-wave?

<sup>1</sup>Continuous Wave.

Comment: CW transmission as meant/used by radio is actually "On/Off Keying" (OOK) amplitude modulation.  The duty cycle is defined by the time the key is on divided by the total time..

Answer (score 1):

> *how can you define the duty cycle for a sine-wave?*

A sinewave does not have a duty cycle. It is predefined mathematically and you can vary amplitude and frequency or phase angle but, there is nothing about duty-cycle that "fits" the definition for a sinewave.

OK you could dream up something like the sinewave being positive for 50% of the time and you might, on some occasions choose to call that duty cycle but, I'm not sure where it gets you.

Answer (score 0):

The only application that I'm familiar with that comes close to your question is variable duty-cycle control of mains powered heaters (but nobody refers to these as "continuous wave" or tone).

[image]

*Figure 1. From [Opto-triacs, solid-state relays (SSR), zero-cross and how they work](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/) (by me).*